# ¿Porqué el evento focus() se me queda enbuclado?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-5

Necesito que al entrar en un input, que se genera dinámicamente, me lance una función que actúe sobre el formato del contenido del mismo, y al salir, se lance otra función que aplique una máscara.
El código donde genero las etiquetas input dinámicamente es algo así:

```
  @{
     for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
     {
           <tr>
           <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => @Model[i].Imp, "{0:n2}", new { @id = "Imp_" + i, @class = "form-control text-right mascara" })</td>
           <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => @Model[i].Ret, "{0:n2}", new { @id = "Ret_" + i, @class = "form-control text-right mascara" })</td>
        </tr>
     }
   }
```

y en el script de la página, de momento tengo este código:

```
  $(function () {
      $('.mascara').focus(function () {
         alert('entra');
      });
   });
```

Al pulsar en el input, efectivamente se lanza el evento y aparece el alert, pero lo hace indefinidamente.
Necesito que solo se ejecute una vez. La idea es que al entrar le quite un formato de máscara a un valor numérico para facilitar su edición, y al salir la vuelva a aplicar.

Comment: cambia la clase por el identificador al cual quieras que vaya primero, pues **$('.mascara')** te retorna un array con todos los elementos que tienen esa clase

Comment: Intenta evitar el "alert", es posible que esta sea la causa de que se ejecute varias veces (Según el browser). Puedes utilizar un console.log('entra') para hacer el debug, en lugar del alert. Mira: https://jsfiddle.net/camilobernal/amx0w7v9/1/

Comment: El problema es muy claro, cuando pones el `input` en foco, dispara el evento focus y aparece la alerta (ahora la alerta está en foco), luego, al cerrar la alerta, automáticamente el foco vuelve al `input`, por lo que, lógicamente, el evento focus se ejecuta nuevamente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No uses el `alert` con un evento que actua con el foco de un elemento ya que este quitara el foco y lo estara retornando cuando cierres el dialogo.

Podrias mostrar el mensaje en otro elemento, como ser un div

```
$(function () {
   $('.mascara').focus(function () {
     var elemId = $(this).attr('id');
     $('#divMensaje').html("entra: " + elemId);
   });
});
```

puedes adicionar el id o algun otro atributo para determinar en cual ingreso asi evaluas que todos los controles toman el foco